# Spark RDD into Matrix

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD like:

```
(A,AA,1)
(A,BB,0)
(A,CC,0)
(B,AA,2)
(B,BB,1)
(B,CC,4)
```

and I want to convert it into the following RRD:

```
([1,0,0],[2,1,4])
```

the order is important for me since the main propose is using RowMatrix to convert the second RDD to a matrix.

Comment: This isnt intended to be a full answer, but some help to get you started but i believe for this you can use the map() function

Comment: Could you provide more details? Is it dense data? Do you know number of columns beforehand? What happens if number of rows / columns > 26?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to be careful with the wording, when you ask for a Matrix, do you mean something like the `spark.mllib.matrix` ? If so, you will need to follow very specific instructions to create one. However, it seems to me that your problem can be solved in a much easier way. Just using `zipWithIndex` with `groupBy`

```
//Here is how I see it
val test = sc.parallelize(Array(("A","AA",1),("A","BB",0),("A","CC",0),("B","AA",2),("B","BB",1),("B","CC",4))).zipWithIndex
val grouptest = test.groupBy(_._1._1).map(x=>(Vectors.dense(x._2.map(y=>(y._2,y._1._3)).toArray.sortBy(_._1).map(z=>z._2.toDouble))))
```

In your example, you seem to want the result as a vector? So I used spark's Vector (which by the way, only allows Doubles).

Result looks like:
    [1.0,0.0,0.0]
    [2.0,1.0,4.0]